# mysterious error with Angular/node

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Can anyone explain what was the problem with my code.
Thank you a lot!!!

- **webpack**: Failed to compile.
- **My Angular CLI**: 1.6.3
- **Node**: 8.9.4
- **OS**: win32 x64
- **Angular**: 5.2.1

**Error Message:**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module build failed: Syntax Error

(6:1) Unknown word

  4 |   * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
  5 |   */
> 6 | (function (global, factory) {
    | ^
  7 |   typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports, require('jquery'), require('popper.js')) :
  8 |   typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports', 'jquery', 'popper.js'], factory) :

 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.css 3:10-163
 @ ./src/styles.css
 @ multi ./src/styles.css
ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/app/firebase.app.module.d.ts(5,22): error TS2420: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'App'.
  Property 'firestore' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.
node_modules/angularfire2/app/firebase.app.module.d.ts(12,28): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts(14,62): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts(15,48): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts(16,92): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_object_observable.d.ts(11,31): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_object_observable.d.ts(12,37): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_object_observable.d.ts(13,24): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts(12,32): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts(13,35): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts(14,35): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts(15,44): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
```

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: Specifically, add your webpack configuration and your package.json. I'm guessing that there is a config error here.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with this configuration. I had an import command inside styles.css file which is no longer supported by Angular. Just remove that import, this worked for me.

If you need the styles from that import, just copy the file from corresponding package inside node_modules and paste it in your assets/css folder, link the css file to index.html file. Done.